# How to implement reactive concurrent consumer with Spring Cloud Stream and the RabbitMQ binder

Tags: java, spring, rabbitmq, spring-cloud-stream

I'm trying to configure concurrent consumers with spring cloud stream (SCS) in reactive mode with the RabbitMQ binder.

It can easily be achieved in non reactive by simply configuring the consumer concurrency property:

```
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.input.consumer.concurrency=5
```

In reactive it is not possible, SCS throws an exception that states that concurrency has to be delegated to reactor (`Concurrency > 1 is not supported by reactive consumer, given that project reactor maintains its own concurrency mechanism`).

I looked how to do that with reactor but it seems it is not [supported](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream/issues/1696) and moreover when i try it anyway, the messages are acked (ack mode auto) before being processed by my code.

```
    public Function<Flux<Event>, ParallelFlux<Event>> function() {
        return flux -> flux
                .parallel()
                .runOn(Schedulers.parallel())
                .map(event -> doSmth(event));

    }
```

Any idea on how can it be implemented?

Comment: You have to use manual acks when using reactor to consume messages.

Comment: Thanks @GaryRussell for the info. Is it ok to use `ParallelFlux` or the comments of olegz still applied ?